# Disable ListView scroll bouncing

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

is somehow possible to disable scroll bouncing using classic ListView?

```
<ListView [items]="countries">
    <ng-template let-country="item" let-i="index" let-odd="odd" let-even="even">
        <StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `bounces` attribute to `false` on the native view (UITableView).

```
onLoaded(args) {
    if (args.object.ios) {
        args.object.ios.bounces = false;
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=zrpwNg)